# "Distorted" differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, differential

Are there any results on differential equations of the type $y'(t)+y(g(t))=f(t)$? I am discarding Delay Differential Equations for which a big body of work already exists.

As an example, we could first assume that $g(t)=2t$ above.

Comment: The notion you're looking for is "Functional differential equation" - you can start with wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation

Comment: @JanczarKnurek yes, I see but most examples are in the area of delayed (or retarded) differential equations. However, it looks interesting that the page mentions $x'(t) = 3x(2t)-(x(t-1))^2$ which is not far from "my" example". These DEs seem quite difficult to manipulate... I'll have a quick look at the books mentioned as references. Thank you